# jquery $.post returned data from php is empty

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post, echo

i'm using this code to post to a php page:

```
var qreq = ".....myurl.php";
$.post(qreq, function(data){alert(data);});
```

in my PHP file i have this:

```
......
$prevtopic = $row["topic_id"];
echo $prevtopic;
```

the alert comes up, but is blank. for some reason data is empty even though i'm echoing from the PHP file. i also tried just echoing "hi" but that didn't work either. what am i doing wrong?

thanks.

Comment: Is the PHP file on the same domain?

Comment: no, but that shouldn't matter, right? i am using the full url in the request.

Comment: guess we to see more of your code to tell you! first of all make sure you use the correct url, probably you can make that sure by entering it in the browser; to see more about the data sent between your browser and the server, try something like firebug (https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/1843/), which can show you in it's console the called url, what data is being posted etc...

Comment: Ajax requests like the one you are making need to be on the same domain for security purposes.

Comment: the url is correct; the echos come out fine when i run the php straight from a browser. also, i can tell the .post is working because i'm able to insert data into the database through the php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make a request cross-domain like this, what's blocking you is called the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), in place to prevent malicious cross-domain requests (even if your's doesn't have evil intent, it's still blocked).

You can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) for this situation, but not get normal html/text content as you have it.  [Here's a short writeup with a better description on JSONP](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/08/27/jquery-post-jsonp-and-cross-domain-requests/), or [here for a full example](http://a.webvm.net/) but [you need to return JSONP from PHP](http://www.carolinamantis.com/wordpress/?p=29).

As for the *why?* It's because `http://evil.com/` shouldn't be able to make requests to `http://mybank.com` without some checks in place, that's why the policy exists.

Comment: Cross-domain GET requests are allowed :)

Comment: everything in the php executes correctly through this .post, and stuff is inserted into my database. how come this works despite the policy? does the policy just prevent data from being transmitted from the php to js?

Comment: @vee - The policy allows you to hit the server, but blocks the response, this is why `data` is empty.

Comment: @Anpher: Not with AJAX, if it's an image, or actually loading a script, iframe, etc sure.  But, my page isn't allowed to fire up a request to your gmail page, and get the username field back (if you have auto-completion for example, which most people do)...the server will get the request, but my page won't get the data back...I'm hoping this is for obvious reasons given my examples.